# GIT show only the number of lines "Updated"

Tags: git, git-diff, git-log

Just wondering if this is possible in GIT commandline.

I'm trying to find the number of lines "updated" between two revisions. I have been able to find help to use git diff with --stat and --shortstat --numstat options. It appears to be that it only shows me #of lines added and deleted. Even if a line is updated, it is counted as 1 delete and 1 insert. Is this true? Is there an option or any utilities (commandline) to give me a breakdown of #lines inserted, updated and deleted?

Comment: `Even if a line is updated, it is counted as 1 delete and 1 insert. Is this true?` Yes, it is.

Comment: Thanks, is there any option to compute the #lines updated? ie the lines that are falling into the bucket of 1 delete and 1 insert.

Comment: So far as I know there is no such option. It's technically hard to tell the difference between "an update" and "1 delete and 1 insert". If only one word is changed in the line that has 10 words in total, we could say it's an update. How about two words? Three words? All words?

Answer (score 1):

While the ability to do it directly from Git doesn't exist (at least as of 2.13.0), you can do it yourself by parsing the unified diff, provided you make some assumptions about what constitutes a changed line.

If N deletions followed by N additions = N changed lines, then here's a GNU awk-based solution, which just outputs the number of lines added/deleted/changed in a unified diff patch:

```
BEGIN {
  inhunk = 0
  adds = 0
  deletes = 0
  changes = 0

  hunk_adds = 0
  hunk_deletes = 0
}

function calcChanges() {
  delta = hunk_adds - hunk_deletes
  changes += (hunk_deletes < hunk_adds ? hunk_deletes : hunk_adds)
  adds += (delta > 0 ? delta : 0)
  deletes += (delta < 0 ? -delta : 0)

  hunk_adds = 0
  hunk_deletes = 0
}

/^@@|^diff/ {
  calcChanges()
  inhunk = ($1 == "@@") ? 1 : 0
}

/^+/ {
  if (inhunk) {
    hunk_adds += 1
  }
}

/^-/ {
  if (inhunk) {
    hunk_deletes += 1
  }
}

/^ / {
  if (inhunk && hunk_adds + hunk_deletes > 0) {
    calcChanges()
  }
}

END {
  calcChanges()

  print "Lines added: " adds
  print "Lines deleted: " deletes
  print "Lines changed: " changes
}
```

This script would be run like so:

```
git diff ... | awk -f path/to/script.awk 

Lines added: 1
Lines deleted: 11
Lines changed: 2
```

The above considers a set of N lines changed if there are N deletions immediately followed by N additions in a hunk. For example:

```
diff --git a/blah.txt b/blah.txt
index deadbeef..ba5eba11 100644
--- a/blah.txt
+++ b/blah.txt
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
 context
-deleted line
-deleted line
+added line
+added line
 context
```

... counts a 2 changed lines.

```
diff --git a/blah.txt b/blah.txt
index deadbeef..ba5eba11 100644
--- a/blah.txt
+++ b/blah.txt
@@ -1,3 +1,4 @@
 context
-deleted line
+added line
+added line
 context
```

... counts as 1 changed line and 1 added line.

```
diff --git a/blah.txt b/blah.txt
index deadbeef..ba5eba11 100644
--- a/blah.txt
+++ b/blah.txt
@@ -1,4 +1,3 @@
 context
-deleted line
-deleted line
+added line
 context
```

... counts as 1 changed line and 1 deleted line.

Finally,

```
diff --git a/blah.txt b/blah.txt
index deadbeef..ba5eba11 100644
--- a/blah.txt
+++ b/blah.txt
@@ -1,6 +1,6 @@
 context
+added line
 context
-deleted line
+added line
 context
-deleted line
 context
```

... counts as 1 added line, 1 changed line, and 1 deleted line.

The script could be expanded to list these stats per file, but I've kept it simple to show the general idea.